# GNUPLOT: Trying to increase the quality

Tags: image, graph, gnuplot, histogram

How do I increase the quality in gnuplot?  It seems like it's a very low-res image.

Here's the contents of the file i'm using: linkage.plot

```
set terminal pdf
set out 'linkage.pdf'

set title "Distribution of Scores"
set xlabel "Score Value"
set ylabel "Appearences"

set yrange [0:50000]
set xrange [0:70]

binwidth=.25
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

plot 'linkage.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) title "Scores"\
smooth freq with boxes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gnuplot pdf output is usually pretty good (it's implemented via the cairo pdf library with antialiasing etc).  but here some points that may help:

- `help terminal pdf` at the `gnuplot>` prompt will give some help about plotting to pdf.
- `set terminal pdf linewidth 1` will give you a thicker line width.
- [deleted - my mistake]

Comment: thank you! I didn't even think to check gnuplot> command help section.  Great call.

I don't know much about 'smooth freq' -- Is there something I should use instead? I found that from here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot

Comment: ah; i may have misunderstood what that was for.  i didn't recognise it and after searching thought it was the "old" way of doing histograms, but your link shows it is slightly different.  so best ignore that.  in fact i'll delete it, sorry.