# How can I draw a simple histogram with three variables?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to unix and shell. I want to know how to draw a simple histogram with three variables which will be read from a file. The variables are random numbers that range from 1 to 100 and they will go to the Y scale and the X scale will be the time stamp of 10 minute.

Comment: Do you have to use bash?  I can imagine better solutions in python or perl, for example, given those languages' file handling...

Comment: Why bash, if you still want to, take a look at [spark](https://github.com/holman/spark)

Comment: If you would accept invoking gnuplot from the command line you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot

Comment: I have to use bash. Because all the other random generator and saving to the file and calculating the averages are written in bash. Is it possible to write in bash?

Comment: I like to draw a histogram like graph and point out all the variables.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed some sample data and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data consists only of integers.

**Edit 2:**

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=40
xtoggle=true
pad=5
xtitle='Seconds'
footnote='5 second intervals'
ytitle='Number (1-100)'
printf '  %*s\n' "$((limit/2 + ${#ytitle}/2 + pad))" "$ytitle"

printf ' %*d' "$pad" 0
for ((i = 5; i <= limit; i += 5))
do
    printf '%5d' "$i"
done
printf '\n\n'

while read -r -a data
do

    printf -v bar '%*s' "$limit" ''
    for i in "${data[@]}"
    do
        bar=${bar:0:i}x${bar:i+1}
    done
    if $xtoggle
    then
        xc=''
        xtoggle=false
    else
        xc="${xtitle:x++:1}"
        xtoggle=true
    fi
    printf '%-*s' "$pad" "$xc"
    printf '%s\n' "$bar"
done < bardata
if $xtoggle
then
    printf '\n'
fi
for ((i = x; i <= ${#xtitle}; i++))
do
    printf '%s\n\n' "${xtitle:i:1}"
done
printf '\n%s\n' "$footnote"
```

With this data:

```
0 5 10
10 13 16
14 3 25
8 4 12
2 20 11
5 17 19
7 8 7
14 19 30
27 22 18
11 19 23
3 33 13
8 5 1
36 18 12
```

This is the output:

```
                    Number (1-100)
     0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40

     x    x    x
S              x  x  x
        x          x          x
e        x   x   x
       x        x        x
c         x           x x
            xx
o                  x    x          x
                       x   x    x
n               x       x   x
        x         x                   x
d     x   x  x
                 x     x                 x
s




5 second intervals
```

**Previous Edit:**

```
while read -r -a data
do

    for i in "${data[@]}"
    do
        printf -v bar '%*s' "$i" ''

        bar=${bar// /*}

        printf '%s\n' "$bar"
    done
    printf '\n'
done < inputfile
```

For this data:

```
10 12 13
4 5 6
8 4 7
```

This is the output:

```
**********
************
*************

****
*****
******

********
****
*******
```

**Original Answer** (None of the indirection trickery below is necessary.
):

```
while read -r -a data
do

    for i in "${!data[@]}"
    do
        printf -v "bar$i" '%*s' "${data[i]}" ''

        temp=bar$i
        declare "bar$i"=${!temp// /*}

        printf '%s\n' "${!temp}"
    done
    printf '\n'
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I want to draw like a graph with x scale and y scale. Thanks.

Comment: @soe: The Y scale is horizontal and the X scale is vertical. Please edit your answer and show some sample data and what you'd like the output to look like.

Comment: Thanks. My scenerio is i have three variables produce at every lets say 5 seconds and i want to show the time interval at x scale and the variables on y scale. So that one time interval will point at 3 different variables on the graph.

Comment: @soe: That's *exactly* what my script is doing. I can't make it do more based only on guesses. Until you provide more information as I have asked for, I can't do anything more. Your comment simply restates what was already in your question.

Comment: @soe: Doubles, as in floating point numbers? Two problems, Bash doesn't understand any numbers except integers and character cells on the screen have integral width. You can deal with both of these issues by using `bc` or `awk` to scale the floats and convert the floats to ints (losing some detail). If you want a graph of float values, I would recommend that you use something that produces graphical output like gnuplot.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be hard to do with gnuplot. I have awk to do the average of five numbers and cast it into integer and save to another file and do the histogram. Any link to gnuplot for begineers?

Comment: @soe: If you've already got an awk script, why don't you have it do the histogram? The same techniques in my answer above could be used. Sorry, I don't have any links for you.