# Perl int function and padding zeros

Tags: perl

1. I have the below Perl function to display up to two decimals places. It's not working when the input value is 2.01, and it gives the output as 2 instead of 2.01. I am not sure why it's rounding.

Instead of printf I wrote the output to a file, but still it gives me output1 as 2.

```
    my $ramount = 2.01;
    $ramount = int($ramount*100)/100;
    printf "output1: $ramount";
```

2. If I have values like .2, .23, .2345, 1,23, 23.1, and 9, what function can I use to pad zeros so that it displays 0.2, 0.23, 0.2345, 1, 23, 23.1, and 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this sequence will answer your question:

```
  DB<1> $a=2.01

  DB<2> p $a
2.01
  DB<3> printf "%20.10f\n", $a
        2.0100000000

  DB<4> printf "%20.16f\n", $a
  2.0099999999999998

  DB<5> printf "%20.16f\n", ($a*100)
200.9999999999999716

  DB<6> printf "%20.16f\n", ($a*100)/100
  2.0099999999999998

  DB<7> printf "%20.16f\n", int($a*100)
200.0000000000000000

  DB<8> printf "%20.16f\n", int($a*100)/100
  2.0000000000000000

  DB<9>
```

Essentially (and this has been answered many times on SO), 2.01 cannot be represented EXACTLY as a floating point number.  The closest possible float is, as you see above, 2.009999999999999716...

As to padding, try

```
printf "%04d", $number
```

The leading zero in the format tells `printf` (or `sprintf`) to left-pad with zero.

Answer (score 1):

From [`perldoc perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-is-int%28%29-broken%3f):

> ### Why is int() broken?
>
> Your [`int()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html) is most probably working just fine. It's the numbers that
>   aren't quite what you think. First, see the answer to ["Why am I
>   getting long decimals (eg, 19.9499999999999) instead of the numbers I
>   should be getting (eg,
>   19.95)?"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-%28eg%2c-19.9499999999999%29-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-%28eg%2c-19.95%29%3f).
>
> For example, this
>
> ```
> print int(0.6/0.2-2), "\n";
> ```
>
> will in most computers print 0, not 1, because even such simple
>   numbers as 0.6 and 0.2 cannot be presented exactly by floating-point
>   numbers. What you think in the above as 'three' is really more like
>   2.9999999999999995559.

Comment: Also, it must be noted, that int() is a truncation operation, rather than a rounding operation.  I = int(f +0.5) is the explicit rounding solution.