# gnuplot - Select bin center in histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm plotting a histogram with the commands:

```
n=3
max=0.5
min=-2.5
width=(max-min)/n
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0
plot "< awk '{if (\$1<3.9 && \$1>3.8) {print \$0}}' /path_to_file/" u (hist(\$2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "black" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitle
```

which gets me this:

[image: histogram]

Apparently, I'm guessing based on the data file, `gnuplot` is deciding by itself to choose the intervals [1.0:0.0]-[0.0:-1.0]-[-1.0:-2.0] which makes the bins centered in [0.5:-0.5:-1.5]

I need those bins to use the intervals [0.5:-0.5]-[-0.5:-1.5]-[-1.5:-2.5] which would make the bins centered in [0.0:-1.0:-2.0]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you just want to change labels on the x-axis?

Comment: Hi @mgilson, no I want `gnuplot` to actually use those intervals I wrote and not the ones it appears to be using by its own decision. How can I tell `gnuplot` from what position to start counting to generate the intervals with the width I set?

Comment: So you want to transform `x -> x-0.5`?  Try:  `hist(x,width)=width*floor((x-0.5)/width)+width/2.0`

Comment: mmm I'm not entirely sure of what that is doing but it's not what I need. I need `gnuplot` to center the bins around 0.0, -1.0 and -2.0 (with a width of '1') instead of how they are centered by default which is in 0.5, -0.5 and -1.5. I want `gnuplot` to count the number of objects inside each interval [0.5:-0.5]-[-0.5:-1.5]-[-1.5:-2.5] and **not** what it is doing right now which is counting them in the intervals [1.0:0.0]-[0.0:-1.0]-[-1.0:-2.0].

Answer (score 0):

The interval in your histogram is determined by the function `hist`. `hist` function reduces a range of numbers into a single value, so gnuplot can plot in a bar plot centered at the value returned by `hist` function.

In your original post, `hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2`. Hence, you will get `hist(x,width)=0.5` for `width=1` and `0 <= x < 1`. Eventually, you will get a bar plot centered at `0.5`.

Now, if you want to set your interval as [-0.5:0.5], [-0.5:-1.5], and so on, you may want to change your `hist` function so that it returns `0.0` when `width=1` and `-0.5 <= x < 0.5`.

```
width=1
hist(x,width)=width*floor((x + width/2)/width)
plot "< awk '{if (\$1<3.9 && \$1>3.8) {print \$0}}' /path_to_file/" u (hist(\$2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "black" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitleenter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [binning](/questions/tagged/binning) function you want is

```
hist(x,width)     = width*(floor(x/width+0.5))
```

This is an equivalent but simplified version of the earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13896530/834416

```
hist(x,width)     = width*floor((x + width/2)/width)
```

I had the same issue and posted an answer and sample code and output at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923363/834416