# gnuplot, graphing individual occurrences over a time period

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data from a log file.  I would like to graph how many times an error happened during a time period.

For exmample:

```
09:00:01, error_1, blah blah blah
09:00:10, error_1, blah blah blah
09:00:23, error_1, blah blah blah
09:01:10, error_2, blah blah blah
09:07:01, error_1, blah blah blah
09:07:43, error_1, blah blah blah
09:11:03, error_1, blah blah blah 
09:18:10, error_1, blah blah blah
09:40:57, error_2, blah blah blah 
09:41:23, error_1, blah blah blah
...
23:32:20 error_1
```

So with the above, I would like to plot the values so that I can show a week with individual points being in hour intervals and showing the sum of "error_1" for that hour...  Hope that makes sense.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated! If there is a way to do this entirely with gnuplot that would be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know what day it is?  The log file doesn't seem to include that information ..

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to make gnuplot do the binning to make a [histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot).  The only trick is that you need to filter out rows based on their error codes.  You *could* probably do the filtering in gnuplot, but it's *MUCH* easier to use something like `grep`.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set datafile sep ','
binwidth = 3600  #3600 seconds in an hour.
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
plot for [ERR in "error_1 error_2"] sprintf('<grep %s test.dat',ERR) u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes ti ERR
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the majority of what you are doing here... What is :(1.0) doing?  Also, I am getting a error "all points y undefined!" with an error pointing all the way at the end of the line.

Comment: `(1.0)` is the literal constant 1.  It adds one to the value for each data that falls into the particular bin.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping!  I am getting some errors and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is the gnuplot commands that I am using.

`set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
set xdata time
set terminal png size 1024,768
set output "xxx.png"\n
set format x "%m/%d\n%H:%M"
set xrange ["11/6/2012 20:19":"11/7/2012 10:00"]
binwidth = 3600  #3600 seconds in an hour.
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
plot for [ERR in "HBER RX_FAILURE"] sprintf('<grep %s alarms.csv', ERR) u (bin($5,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes ti ERR`

Comment: Here is a sample of the log that I am trying to plot.

`xxxx/radio-1.4.123123132.1,RX_FAILURE,MAJOR,,11/7/2012 16:52,11/7/2012 16:52<br/>
xxxx/radio-1.4.123123123.1,HBER,MAJOR,,11/7/2012 16:52,11/7/2012 16:52`