# histogram in gnuplot vs histogram in unix utilities

Tags: csv, gnuplot, histogram

I have [csv](http://termbin.com/wd4v) file, I want to create histogram from column 6. Using Linux utilities this is simple:

```
└──> cut -f6 -d, data.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2,2n
    563 0.0
     72 0.025
     35 0.05
     22 0.075
     14 0.1
     21 0.125
     14 0.15
     10 0.175
      5 0.2
      3 0.225
      7 0.25
      3 0.275
      6 0.3
      5 0.325
      3 0.35
      1 0.375
      3 0.4
      1 0.425
      3 0.45
      3 0.475
      5 0.5
      7 0.525
     11 0.55
      3 0.575
      4 0.6
      3 0.625
     11 0.65
      5 0.675
      9 0.7
      5 0.725
      7 0.75
      8 0.775
      5 0.8
      3 0.825
      3 0.85
      4 0.875
      2 0.9
      1 0.925
      1 0.975
    109 1.0
```

But I would like to plot it using `gnuplot` my attempt was to modify [following](http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_frequency.htm) script that I've found. This is my modified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
# http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_frequency.htm

clear
reset

set datafile separator ",";
# set term dumb

set key off
set border 3

# Add a vertical dotted line at x=0 to show centre (mean) of distribution.
set yzeroaxis

# Each bar is half the (visual) width of its x-range.
set boxwidth 0.05 absolute
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder

bin_width = 0.1;
bin_number(x) = floor(x/bin_width)
rounded(x) = bin_width * ( bin_number(x) + 0.5 )

# MAKE BINS
# plot dataset_path using (rounded($6)):(6) smooth frequency with boxes

# DO NOT MAKE BINS
plot "data.csv" using 6:6 smooth frequency with boxes
```

This is the result:

[image: this]

It is saying something completely different than Unix tools. In `gnuplot` I've seen various types of histograms, e.g. some follows normal distribution pattern, others were ordered according to frequency (as if I replace the last `sort -k2,2n` with `sort -n`) another were ordered according to numbers from which histogram was created (mine case), etc. it would be nice if I could choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smooth frequency` renders the data monotonic in x (i.e. the value given in the first `using` column, in your case the numerical value from column 6), and then sums up all y-values (the values given in the second `using` column).

Here you also give the the sixth column, which is wrong if you want to count the number of occurrences of each distinct value in the sixth column, use `using 6:(1)`, i.e. the numerical value `1` in the second column, to count the actual number of occurrences of each value:

```
set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set datafile separator ','
plot 'nupic_out.csv' using 6:(1) smooth frequency with boxes notitle
```

[image]

To apply a logscale to the smoothed data, you must first save them to a temporary file with `set table ...; plot` and then plot this temporary file.

```
set datafile separator ','
set table 'tmp.dat'
plot 'nupic_out.csv' using 6:(1) smooth frequency with lines
unset table
```

Here you must pay attention, because a bug in gnuplot adds a wrong last line to the output file which you must skip. You can either skip this by a filter in the `using` statement with e.g.

```
plot 'tmp.dat' using (strcol(3) eq "i" ? $1 : 1/0):2 with boxes
```

which works fine here, or you could use `head` to cut the last two lines like

```
plot '< head -n-2 tmp.dat' using 1:2 with boxes
```

Another point to note is, that gnuplot always uses white spaces to write out its data files, so you must change the data file separator back to `whitespace` before plotting `tmp.dat`.

A full working script could be

```
set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set datafile separator ','

set table 'tmp.dat'
plot 'nupic_out.csv' using 6:(1) smooth frequency with lines notitle
unset table

set datafile separator whitespace
set logscale y
set yrange [0.8:*]
set autoscale xfix
plot '< head -n-2 tmp.dat' using 1:2 with boxes notitle
```

[image]

Now, using a binning function for the values in the sixth column, you must replace the `6` in `using 6:(1)` by an function which operates on the value given in the sixth column. This function must be enclosed in () and you reference the current value in the sixth column using `$6` inside the function, like

```
plot 'nupic_out.csv' using (bin($6)):(1) smooth frequency with lines
```

Again, a full working script, using [ChrisW's binning function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596160/2604213) could be

```
set style fill solid noborder
set datafile separator ','

set boxwidth 0.09 absolute
Min = -0.05
Max = 1.05
n = 11.0
width = (Max-Min)/n
bin(x) = width*(floor((x-Min)/width)+0.5) + Min

set table 'tmp.dat'
plot 'nupic_out.csv' using (bin($6)):(1) smooth frequency with lines notitle
unset table

set datafile separator whitespace
set logscale y
set xrange [-0.05:1.05]
set tics nomirror out
plot '< head -n-2 tmp.dat' using 1:2 with boxes notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you buddy this worked. Just few questions: 1. can I use log scale on y? I did `set logscale y 10` but the output was mess (also with another numbers). 2. can I reorder the x axis somehow (as I described in OP). 3. What is the purpose of enclosing the numbers inside ()? I've tried various versions with () here `seq 1 12 | xargs -n 2 echo | gnuplot -p -e "set style fill solid noborder; set boxwidth 0.3 relative; plot '-' using 2:1 smooth frequency with boxes notitle"` but I cannot figure it out. Thank you

Comment: 1: No, you cannot directly use log scale on smoothed data, I'll extend my answer to include a possible solution for this. 2. Yes of course, instead of using `6` you can use anything you want as expression in the `using` statement, like `using (rounded($6)):(1)` or similar. But pay attention to the details of your binning function, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19596160/2604213). 3. `using 6:1` would use the sixth column for x and the first column for the y-value. Enclosing something in () makes gnuplot evaluate an expression, `(1)` gives the number 1, not the value in the 1. col