# Gnuplot: plotting histograms by binning in X and summing in Y

Tags: gnuplot, binning

I am trying to plot a binned version of my data file in gnuplot.

My data file looks like this:

```
Y-values    X-values 
5             0.1
6             0.2
2             0.3
4             0.4
```

and so on. For some reason the standard order `X-Y` has been inverted (it is not me who produces the plot, I got it from some other source). I need to bin the data in such a way that the `Y` value is also considered, in the sense that if I group some `X`-values in a bin, I need to sum their respective `Y`-values up and associate the value I get to that bin. For example if my first bin would include 0.1 and 0.2 its associated `y` value would be 11, the sum of 5 and 6. I then need to plot the binned version of my data in Gnuplot. Is there a way to do this all-at-once in Gnuplot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2471884/2604213

Comment: @Christoph but this is assuming that you have in the first column the X values and in the second one the Y values, right? How to change it to my case?

Comment: In a `using` statement, the columns are referred by `$1`, `$2`, you can use them where you like!