# How to create an actual histogram with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

Hi I need to make an histogram with gnuplot. I have a 'file.dat' that contains at each line a certain value. This value represents the occurrence of the value, (more times this value is repeated on the file , higher is the occurence). How I can plot this on a histogram on gnuplot? I have tryed the command:

```
plot "dati.dat" with boxes
```

but is not what I am looking for. 
For example in my case if they value of 'file.dat' are values of a gaussian variable with mean zero, plotting the histogram with gnuplot I would expect an histrogram with the typical gaussian shape centered in zero. I do not obtain this using the command I wrote before. 
What I need is the number of the occurence on the ordinate , and the corresponding value on the abscisse.

Comment: Did you see the examples?: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html see also `help histogram` at the `gnuplot>` prompt.

Comment: Hi! Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot help?