# How to plot histogram using gnuplot

Tags: shell, gnuplot, histogram

I have a file contains wire length ranging from 300-1000. How do I use GNUPLOT to make a histogram with length on X-axis (With interval of 100) and number of wires on Y-axis?

For example:

```
250 wire_0
350 wire_1
360 wire_2
800 wire_3
```

I want a bar with height of 1 representing wire_0, a bar with height of 2 representing wire_1 and wire_2 and a bar with height of 1 representing wire_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit #1**

Based on both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538846/11369382) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592666/11369382) answers, your could try:

```
binwidth = 100
bin(x, width) = width*floor(x/width)

set tics out nomirror
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 border lt -1
set xrange [0:1000]
set xtics binwidth
set boxwidth binwidth
set yrange [0:3]

$data <<EOD
250 wire_0
350 wire_1
360 wire_2
800 wire_3
EOD

plot $data u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes notitle
```

Result

[image: result]

**Edit #2**

If you need the of values above the boxes, you can use.

```
set table $data2
    plot $data u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes;
unset table

plot $data2 u 1:2 w boxes notitle , "" u 1:2:2 w labels offset 0,1 notitle
```

Result
[image: result 2]

Comment: Thank you, but I really want to plot length on X-axis and count on  Y-axis, that way wire_1 and wire_2 will be merged into 1 bar with height of 2 (300~400).

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed "yrange [0:3]" to "yrange[0:*]" and it works beautifully. BTW, if I want to put a text ontop of each bar to show the height how do I do that?